# How to get rid of retain cycle with collectionview

Tags: ios, swift, retain-cycle

I am having trouble destroying viewcontrollers due what I believe to be a retain cycle between a collectionview and the viewcontroller.  I tried making the collectionview a weak variable but I am now getting nil whenever I trying to add the collectionview to the viewcontroller.  If there is another route to try rather than making the collectionview weak I'm open to that as well.

```
weak var table = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0), collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
weak var customFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout() //default cell spacing is 10





table?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 50, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
table?.isHidden = true
table?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
table?.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "customCellIdentifier")
table?.dataSource = self
table?.delegate = self
//table.rowHeight = CGFloat(100)
customFlowLayout?.minimumLineSpacing = 5 //default is 10
table?.collectionViewLayout = customFlowLayout!
self.view.addSubview(table!)  //this is the line that breaks every time
```

Comment: How are you trying to destroy ViewControllers?

Comment: Collection view should not be a problem. Problem is when you hold the direct reference to the view controller, then the view controller cannot be deinited. I bet you do that somewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see any retain cycles from the code you provided. Unless there is a block being passed somewhere, it's likely pretty difficult to have a retain cycle directly caused by a standard `UICollectionView`. If anything it's likely that your view controller holding onto the `UICollectionView` is never being released.

The property on your view controller for the `UICollectionView` can be weak, but you need to declare the local variable as a strong reference (no `weak`) like so:

```
class ViewController : UIViewController {
    weak var collectionView: UICollectionView?

    // Maybe in viewDidLoad()    
    let cv = UICollectionView(...)
    ...
    self.view.addSubview(cv)
    self.collectionView = cv
```

Your local declaration should be a strong reference, otherwise it will be allocated and immediately released because nothing is holding onto it. Once `cv` is added as a subview, then it will have a strong reference from the `view`. Your class's property called `collectionView` can now be a weak reference and the `collectionView` will be released once the view is deallocated.